# class SystemDialog: is not recognizing my system dialog window

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to upload some files to a website and so far I've tried everything I could find and nothing is working. The html input element won't let me sendKeys to it so I found this class to try and use it.

```
class SystemDialog:

RECURSION_LIMIT = 20

def __init__(self, application_pid, dialog_title=None):

    self.__path_to_file = None
    self.__recursions = 0

    self.dialog_title = "Open" if dialog_title is None else dialog_title
    self.accept_button = "&SaveButton" if self.dialog_title == "Save As" else "&OpenButton"
    self.decline_button = "&CancelButton"

    app = pywinauto.application.Application()
    app.connect(process=application_pid)
    self.dialog = app.window(title=self.dialog_title)

def __wait_for_dialog(self):
    start = time.time()
    while not self.dialog.exists() and (time.time() - start) <= 10:
        time.sleep(1)
    if not self.dialog.exists():
        raise Exception("System Dialog did not show in 10 seconds")

def input_file_path(self, path_to_file):
    self.__wait_for_dialog()
    self.__path_to_file = path_to_file
    if path_to_file is not None:
        self.dialog.set_focus()
        self.dialog.Edit.type_keys(self.__path_to_file)
    return self

def accept(self):
    if self.__recursions == SystemDialog.RECURSION_LIMIT:
        raise Exception("Not able to accept the System dialog.")

    self.__wait_for_dialog()
    self.dialog.set_focus()
    self.dialog[self.accept_button].click()

    if self.dialog.exists():
        self.__recursions += 1
        if self.__path_to_file is not None:
            return self.input_file_path(self.__path_to_file).accept()  # <--- FYI Recursion
        else:
            raise Exception("Trying to accept dialog without any inputs, not gonna work.")
    self.__recursions = 0

def decline(self):
    if self.__recursions == SystemDialog.RECURSION_LIMIT:
        raise Exception("Not able to decline the System dialog.")

    self.__wait_for_dialog()
    self.dialog.set_focus()
    self.dialog[self.decline_button].click()

    if self.dialog.exists():
        self.__recursions += 1
        return self.decline()  # <--- Recursion
    self.__recursions = 0
```

Here is the HTML as well
[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwSnm.png)

Here is me trying to send the files in my python code:

```
#Upload files
click(driver, 5, By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dm-react-shared-container"]/div/div[10]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]', False)
click(driver, 5, By.XPATH, '//*[@id="downshift-0-label"]/div[1]/button', False)

process = psutil.Process(driver.service.process.pid)  # chromedriver pid
pid = process.children()[0].pid  # chrome tab pid

dialog = SystemDialog(application_pid=pid)
dialog.input_file_path(path)
dialog.accept()
```

I am met with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "blaineus_v2.py", line 331, in <module>
    main()
  File "blaineus_v2.py", line 64, in main
    uploadPDFs(destination, driver, email, password, projectName)
  File "blaineus_v2.py", line 324, in uploadPDFs
    dialog.input_file_path(path)
  File "blaineus_v2.py", line 91, in input_file_path
    self.__wait_for_dialog()
  File "blaineus_v2.py", line 88, in __wait_for_dialog
    raise Exception("System Dialog did not show in 10 seconds")
Exception: System Dialog did not show in 10 seconds
```